# Android AutoCompleteTextView suggestion if nothing is found

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am making a point of sale app for Android, and I have a AutoCompleteTextView loaded in with the database of items that they can buy, but I also want the AutoCompleteTextView to double as a way to add custom items/notes into the order.

So for example, the customer is ordering Steak, but doesnt want any seasoning. My database includes options for 'No Onions' 'No Mushrooms', etc, but not 'No Seasoning', and if the waiter types in 'No Seasoning' into the AutoCompleteTextView, I want a suggestion 'Add as Note' to pop up.

Is there a way to add this suggestion when no other suggestions are found, either by making it always on the dropdown list (making it not able to be filtered out), or by detecting when no items are on the dropdown list and adding it in then?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).

When you retrieve the cursor from your database, check if its empty with Cursor.moveToFirst(). Then either fill the MatrixCursor with your database cursor or a single "Add as Note" item if empty.

I use this to combine two database Cursor in one for suggestions [here](http://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/source/browse/trunk/src/org/zirco/providers/BookmarksProviderWrapper.java) (method getUrlSuggestions(), the last one). Note that this example is not very clean, as all values are casted to String before insertion in the MatrixCursor. This is not necessary as the addRow() method take an array of Object.